# what does Internet arcticle number of an email mean?

Tags: mapi

what does Internet arcticle number of an email mean?

Comment: Class of email will help...

Answer (score 1):

This is, as far as I know, a property of Microsofts MAPI interface. There is a [reference page for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc815718.aspx)